# Error para autenticar por Get un JSON en C# en una aplicación de consola con Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, .net

Quisiera solicitar su ayuda trato de usar este código con un `webClient` pero solo me resulta en `post` pero no encuentro la forma de poder generar la conexión vía `GET` para recibir la información de una URL, Solicito su ayuda, ya que me tira error.

Quedo muy agradecido.

```
var content = new
            {
                scopes = new[] { "repo" },
                note = "API test",
            };

            var webClient = new WebClient();

            // Crear credenciales, base64 encode con username:password
string credentials = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("username" + ":" + "password"));

            // Authorization header
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = string.Format("Basic {0}", credentials);

            string serializedObject = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);

            string reply = webClient.UploadString(new Uri("URL"), "GET", serializedObject);

            dynamic deserializedReply = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(reply);

            Console.WriteLine(deserializedReply.token);

        }
```

Comment: Podrias mostrar el error que te arroja, tambien confirma con el proveedor si el metodo de peticion `GET` lo tienen habilitado.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que la autenticación te está funcionando (no me queda claro tal como está redactado), para hacer un get y obtener el JSON de respuesta deberías hacer algo como:

```
string reply= webclient.DownloadString("url");
```

Tú estás poniendo `webClient.UploadString` que sería para el POST.

Te recomiento poner un bloque try-catch para así capturar si te lanza una excepción y poder depurar los errores.

```
try
{
//tu código
}
catch(Exception e)
{
//lo que quieras hacer con la excepción, yo mostraría el mensaje como en la siguiente linea:
Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```